# How to conditionally render fields in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, database-administration

I'm trying to create a form that updates a table, but it should be in such that, only those fields that the admin wants to update appear in the form on the next page.
Suppose we choose a row with the id 1 to update,next the admin should be able to choose the fields he wants to update.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a table which contains that page item names (e.g. `P1_ID`, `P1_NAME`, `P1_ADDRESS`, ...) and a column which says whether it'll be rendered or not (let's call it `CB_RENDER`). Admin would update that table and decide whether to render an item (and set `cb_render = 1`) or not. Table contents would then be

```
ITEM_NAME         CB_RENDER
----------------  ---------
P1_ID             1
P1_NAME           1
P1_ADDRESS        0
```

Create a function which accepts item name as argument and returns `cb_render` value:

```
create or replace function f_render_item (par_item_name in varchar2)
  return number
is
  retval number;
begin
  select cb_render
  into retval
  from that_table
  where item_name = par_item_name;

  return retval;
end;
```

Use that function in every item's Server-side condition; its type would be a function that returns Boolean:

```
return f_render_item (:APP_ITEM_NAME) = 1;
```

It evaluates to TRUE if function returns `1` (which means that item will be rendered).

That's all, more or less.